# Use IF statement in trigger to test

Tags: sql, if-statement, triggers

I need to test the `PACK_TYPE` column of a row that was just added and then insert to another table based on what was in that column. I decided to do this with a trigger.

Here is what I have but is not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_INTO_PART_DIM 
ON Qubiscan 
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF PACK_TYPE = 'SELL'
       INSERT INTO PART_DIMENSION (PART_ID, SELL_PACK)
          SELECT part_id, 1
          FROM INSERTED

    IF PACK_TYPE = 'INNER'
       INSERT INTO PART_DIMENSION (PART_ID, INNER_PACK)
          SELECT PART_ID, 1
          FROM INSERTED
    END
END
GO
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... but triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? Postgres? DB2?

Comment: So sorry, MS SQL 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move checking to `where` clause:

```
INSERT INTO PART_DIMENSION (PART_ID, SELL_PACK)
SELECT part_id, 1
FROM INSERTED
WHERE PACK_TYPE = 'SELL'

INSERT INTO PART_DIMENSION (PART_ID, INNER_PACK)
SELECT PART_ID, 1
FROM INSERTED
WHERE PACK_TYPE = 'INNER'
```

You can do it with single statement:

```
INSERT INTO PART_DIMENSION (PART_ID, SELL_PACK, INNER_PACK)
SELECT part_id, 
       CASE WHEN PACK_TYPE = 'SELL' THEN 1 END,
       CASE WHEN PACK_TYPE = 'INNER' THEN 1 END
FROM INSERTED
WHERE PACK_TYPE IN('SELL', 'INNER')
```